# tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.auth'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a Flutter web app with Firebase integrated to handle authentication. I've gone through the usual process of setting up the firebase app but when I come to run my app on Chrome I get the following message:

```
    The following JSNoSuchMethodError was thrown building Consumer<OurUser>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<OurUser>]):
NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.auth'
```

Here is my index.html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    Fore more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="rafflello">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>rafflello</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: apiKey,
    authDomain: authDomain,
    projectId: projectId,
    storageBucket: storageBucket,
    messagingSenderId: messagingSenderId,
    appId: appId,
    measurementId: measurementId
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my pubspec.yaml (might be slightly misaligned here but ok in file):

```
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1
```

I've tried the firebase configuration inside the head tags and body. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this part of my index.html file

```
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

was in the wrong order. firebase-app.js needs to be **before** firebase-auth.js.

App is now working